# No Match for 'Operator>>' in 's>>local"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, operator-keyword

This function is preventing Wagic: the homebrew from Compiling:

/home/white/Pandora/wagic-read-only/projects/mtg/src/GameOptions.cpp:1156: error: no match for ‘operator>>’ in ‘s >> local’

Source(GameOptions.cpp): http://code.google.com/p/wagic/source/browse/trunk/projects/mtg/src/ GameOptions.cpp
Source(General):
http://code.google.com/p/wagic/source/browse/

(Line 1142-1172)

```
    bool GameOptionKeyBindings::read(string input)
{
istringstream iss(input);
vector<pair<LocalKeySym, JButton> > assoc;

while (iss.good())
{
    stringstream s;
    iss.get(*(s.rdbuf()), ',');
    iss.get();

    LocalKeySym local;
    char sep;
    u32 button;
    s >> local >> sep >> button; 
    if (':' != sep)
        return false;
    assoc.push_back(make_pair(local, u32_to_button(button)));
}

if (assoc.empty())
    return false;

JGE* j = JGE::GetInstance();

j->ClearBindings();
for (vector<pair<LocalKeySym, JButton> >::const_iterator it = assoc.begin(); it != assoc.end(); ++it)
    j->BindKey(it->first, it->second);

return true;
}
```

How would I rewrite this to get it to compile?

Answer (score 2):

```
s >> local
```

Calls the default `operator >>` which does not understand your custom class `LocalKeySym` So You need to Overload the `Operator >>` for your custom class `LocalKeySym`.

An sample code:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, LocalKeySym& obj) 
{ 
  // read LocalKeySym obj from stream 

  if( /* no valid object of LocalKeySym found in stream */ )
       is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);

  return is;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`operator >>` is defined only for built-in types like, `int`, `float`, `char`, `double` etc. and it can input the address using pointers. Since your variable `local` is of custom type `LocalKeySym`. you may have to define your own `operator >>`.

It should be similar to overloading istream and ostream operators. See the [tutorial here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Cpp/0200__Operator-Overloading/Classlevelostreamoperatorandistreamoperator.htm).